# crontab runs script with a python command but the python program crashes

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron

This is what `crontab -l` displays:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

*/1 *   *   *   * /bin/bash  /home/azureuser/project/negev/restart.sh >> /home/azureuser/out.txt 2>&1
```

This is the content of the `restart.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/azureuser/project/negev

variable=$(ps x aux | grep -i 'main.py' | wc -l)
if test $variable=='1'
then
    /home/azureuser/miniconda3/envs/negev/bin/python '/home/azureuser/project/negev/main.py'
fi
```

When I run `main.py` or `restart.sh` everything is super. However, when I go check the `out.txt` file I see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    from logger import logger, logger_format
  File "/home/azureuser/project/negev/logger.py", line 8, in <module>
    log_path = config['LOGGER']['log_path']
  File "/home/azureuser/miniconda3/envs/negev/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'LOGGER
```

The config file is in `/home/azureuser/project/negev/user`

I cannot understand why this is happening only when using `crontab`, and I have failed to find a solution anywhere.

EDIT: The problem is related to me using relative paths in the code and not the absolute paths. Is there a way to overcome this without changing every single relative path in my project?

Comment: Does the config have a `LOGGER` key as the code is expecting?

Comment: @jordanm It does indeed, as the code is running successfully if I call it directly.

Comment: @jordanm The problem is related to me using relative paths in the code and not the absolute paths. Is there a way to overcome this without changing every single relative path in my project?

Comment: It's hard to say because I can't see where and how you're using paths in your code. Generally it's the opposite, you want to avoid absolute paths in your codebase because that makes it easier to move to different systems

Comment: You could have the script `cd` to the appropriate directory first (but check for errors on the `cd` command -- if it fails, the rest of the script will run in the wrong directory). BTW, `test $variable=='1'` is wrong, you need spaces around the operator, and `==` is nonstandard with `test` and you probably want `-eq` anyway. You may also have trouble with `ps` listing the `grep` command; `pgrep` would be better for this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson. Thank you for your input. The first thing I tried was to change the directory, however that (surprisingly to me) didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Something is different in the environment you use and the one into which crontab runs your script.    You could add `source /home/YOURUSER/.bashrc` to load it.  Also, your if should be `if [[ "$variable" -eq 1 ]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `os.chdir` ​to your python code?

```py
import os

os.chdir('/home/azureuser/project/negev')

# or
# os.chdir('/path/to/your/project/folder')
# os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```